# speed issues android wear

Tags: android, wear-os

My situation is rather simple. I have a mobile and wear app. My mobile app is a "drawing" app. It connects to a piece of hardware that has a magnetic pencil. Drawing on the hardware sends three functions to my app - touchStart, touchMove, touchStop. I can draw the path on my mobile app at a reasonable rate. But, if I send these 3 touch detections to my watch via SendMessage, the image is drawn slowly. I'm trying to speed it up so the drawing is in a real time, like the mobile device.

Here's the code to the Paint class of my watch app:

```
class SimpleDrawingView extends View {
    // setup initial color
    private final int paintColor = Color.WHITE;
    // defines paint and canvas
    private Paint drawPaint;
    // Store circles to draw each time the user touches down

     public int xwidth, xheight;
     private Path bPath = new Path();
     private Path path = new Path();
     public SimpleDrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
         super(context, attrs);
         setFocusable(true);
         setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
         setupPaint();
     }


     public Path redraw() {

         Matrix m = new Matrix();
         RectF innerBounds = new RectF();

         bPath = new Path(path);


         bPath.computeBounds(innerBounds, true);


         int width = getWidth();
         int height = getHeight();
         RectF intoBounds = new RectF(0, 0, width, height);
         m.setRectToRect(innerBounds, intoBounds, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);


         bPath.transform(m);



         return bPath;
     }


     // Draw each circle onto the view
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
         Log.d("MEx", " drawing ");
         redraw();


        canvas.drawPath(path, drawPaint);
    }

    public void actionDown(Point a)
    {

        path.moveTo(a.x, a.y);
        invalidate();


    }

    public void clear()
    {
        path.reset();
        invalidate();
    }

    public void actionEnd(Point a)
    {
      //  path.lineTo(a.x, a.y);
    }
    public void actionMove(Point a)
    {
        path.lineTo(a.x, a.y);
        invalidate();
    }
    // Append new circle each time user presses on screen



     private void setupPaint() {
         // Setup paint with color and stroke styles
         drawPaint = new Paint();
         drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
         drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
         drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(23);
         drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
         drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
         drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
     }
}
```

Here's my message receiver:

```
 public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



            for(String s : intent.getExtras().keySet()) {




                String first = intent.getExtras().get(s).toString();

                String label, x, y;

                if (first.contains("charge+")) {



                    textLabel.setText(first.split("7")[1]);

                } else if (first.contains("battery+")) {
                    String color = first.substring(8);

                    Log.d("TESTTWO", color + " <- ");

                    switch(color)
                    {
                        case "RED":
                            dotView.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
                            textLabel.setText("");

                            break;
                        case "GREEN":
                            dotView.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);
                            textLabel.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                            break;
                        case "YELLOW":
                            textLabel.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                            dotView.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
                            break;
                    }

                } else {
                    label = first.substring(0, 1);


                    String[] toSplit;

                    toSplit = first.substring(2).split(",");


                    Point point = new Point(Integer.parseInt(toSplit[0]), Integer.parseInt(toSplit[1]));

                    switch (label) {
                        case "S":
                            imageView.actionDown(point);
                            break;
                        case "M":
                            imageView.actionMove(point);
                            break;
                        case "E":
                            imageView.actionEnd(point);

                            break;
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Points are sent to my watch in the format of either

S-x,y
M-x,y
E-x,y

S = start, M = move, E = end.

If someone can help me optimize this functionality it would be amazing!

I tried send the data as an asset as well, that's even slower.

Comment: Is your lag in drawing or in message passing?  The drawing can definitely be much more efficient (you should never call new in onDraw, reuse objects instead).  But I doubt its your problem.  If its in message passing-  you have a pointer connected to your phone, connected to your watch.  I'd try to remove the middleman.  Or do it over a different mechanism than a broadcast receiver-  those aren't meant for speed.  A bluetooth socket makes more sense for real time communication.

Comment: The lag appears as I draw, but I can't tell if it's the drawing or the message passing going slow

Comment: @GabeSechan anc you show me documents about how to do the communication via a bluetooth socket for android wear? That'd be amazing!